# How do i display post from a taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

Hey i was wondering how could i show post from a certain taxonomy term in the loop.

```
 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

I have a taxonomy entitled "series" under my post type entitled "Gallery", and in "series" i have the TERM "pretty-little-liars". Under my **post type** "pretty-litte-liars" archive it shows all the post posted in that CPT. I would like to add a code that also allows post posted under the taxonomy "series" with the term "pretty-little-liars" to show on that page as well.

what do i add to the above excerpt code to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$type = 'buehne';  // Name of the Custom Post Types
$tag =  'TagName';


$args =  array(
        'post_type' => $type, 
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC', 
                'tax_query'=>array(
                    array(
            'taxonomy'=>'th3', //name of the Taxonom 
            'field'=>'slug',
            'terms'=>array($tag)
                            ))
                    );



$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    if(is_object_in_term($post->ID,'th3','TagName')) {  
        the_title(); ";

    }
endwhile;
```

Comment: this looks complicated, where do i add this

Comment: You have to Query a new loop with the Parameters you like to output. Place this code in your Template. with the Line  is_object_in_term() you can filter the output you want. You could search in the codex page for custom post types and for is_object_in_term